# Как на PHP сделать ссылку, без указания файла PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, site

1. Как на PHP сделать ссылку подобную этой: localhost/ysKg1Ch . Я хочу написать фотохостинг, но с моими навыками, всё будет сводится к ссылке подобного плана: localhost/view. php?photo=ysKg1Ch . Как мне при случайно сгенерированной ссылке, незаметно ссылаться на файл view.php, передавая ysKg1Ch в качестве параметра. В итоге, я хочу получить localhost/ysKg1Ch.
2. Аналогично и с localhost/ysKg1Ch/delete , т.е. уже перейти к обработчику по удалению фото

Comment: php тут (почти) ни при чём, для этого нужно настраивать веб-сервер так, чтобы для ссылки определённого формата выполнял нужные действия (в данном случае запускал указанный php-файл)

Comment: @andreymal отчего же, можно и чисто на php написать маршрутизатор

Comment: @АлексейШиманский все равно реврайтами надо перенаправить все запросы куда-то в одно место тогда.

Comment: @teran это да. три строчки htaccess не помешают))